# ng-repeat item reference is showing up differently in angular ui router link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a `ng-repeat` for an array of message objects, which prints out `message.text` and is accompanied by `message.author.username`. When I use `{{message.author.username}}`, it prints out the correct user, but I have that DOM element wrapped in an anchor, where `ui_sref=profile(message.author.username)` is set as the link.

For some reason the ui-sref link's reference to the username is presenting something totally different than what it's wrapped around. Like, when I hover over the linked username on the site, it shows that the link goes to a different username found later in the array. If it's using the same exact syntax (message.author.username) is there any reason for the text to be different when listed in an ui-router anchor tag? I feel like it's a bug but I'm not sure why and how to fix.

Hopefully that made sense... here's some code to be clear

```html
<div class="col-sm-9 offset-sm-1"
     ng-repeat="message in wall | orderBy: createdon:true | limitTo: 8">
    <div class="comment-container">
        <div >
            <h6> <a ui-sref="profile(message.author.username)">{{message.author.username}}</a></h6>
        </div>

        <div class="comment-text">              
             {{message.text}}
        </div>
        <hr>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your `profile` function look like?

Comment: It's to pass in parameters to ui router. Actually, your comment made me realize I had to put an object as the argument, with the key set to the parameter you want in the link (I wanted ?username = user's handle). Thanks for your comment! @Varedis